# vagrant add box laravel/homestead

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, homestead

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 but alas my laravel homestead environment collapsed ... after 2 days trying to reconfig this problem i decided to roll back to Windows 8 (more time wasting) ... I downloaded Virtualbox 4.3.30 and Vagrant 1.7.4 succsessfully... following the Homestead documentation ... when I try to 'vagrant add box laravel/homestead' i get this output in my git bash screen ...

```
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
```

could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead"]
Error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.

can someone please point me towards a fix for this problem ... regards

Answer (score 6):

Installing MS Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributables worked for me: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6764

Comment: Awesome. I didn't have any error about SSL, it was just blank. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install and run this file: https://www.virtualbox.org/attachment/ticket/14040/VBox-Win10-fix-14040.exe (leave it running in the background) Go to the C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox folder, right click on VirtualBox.exe, go to compatibility, check the "Run in compatibility mode" checkbox and choose Windows 7/8.

Then go to you command prompt and try the vagrant add box.

Credits from https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/windows-10-vagrant-virtualbox-homestead

Check out the forum and thread to see solution fixes for problems encountered.